# Prototype / Scriptaculous Javascript plugin for a file browser that integrates with JSP / Java?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, prototypejs, scriptaculous

I've been tasked with building a new Javascript file browser but unfortunately I have to use Prototype and can't use Jquery (at least not at the moment) due to some issues that may arise from conflicts (they have said they plan to resolve this but for the moment it looks like I may have to go with prototype). I've been searching on google for plugins that I can use for Prototype / Scriptaculous but they seem few and far between and all the ones I have found are geared towards use with PHP. I figure I may be able to rewrite the PHP end to Java / JSP as our application is built with Java. I just figured I would post here to see if anyone can recommend a good plugin for this that could easily be made to integrate with Java. Thanks

EDIT: This is what I mean:

http://abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/03/jquery-file-tree/ (this is in Jquery) so I need something like this for Prototype

This is for browsing the file system of the server, not the client, so there would be a server-side page / controller that returns an HTML list, of sorts, of the files / folders and then the JavaScript manipulates this as needed to collapse / expand. There are a bunch of these written in Jquery but unfortunately I can't seem to find one written with Prototype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by Diodeus, and as demonstrated by your own example, and as probably used by most file browser plugins available it works on HTML being rendered and returned by the server. All the javascript needs to do is insert the returned HTML, Prototype has a function which does most of that for you, [`Ajax.Updater`](http://api.prototypejs.org/ajax/Ajax/Updater/). You could write your own very quickly.

```
function expandCollapseFolder(event, folder) {
    var list = folder.down('ul');
    if (list) list.toggle();
    else new Ajax.Updater(folder, 'URL-OF-SERVER-PAGE',
    {
        parameters: { path: folder.readAttribute('data-path') },
        insertion: 'bottom'
    });
}

Event.on('ID-OF-FILE-BROWSER', 'click', 'li.folder', expandCollapseFolder);
```

The above is not tested code, it is meant to show how little is needed in total. The hard work is done by the server, it needs to scan and return folder contents with the appropriate file icons and URLs.

```
<ul>
    <li class="folder" data-path="/folder">
        <img src="folder-icon.png" />This is a folder
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="URL-OF-FILE" target="_blank">
            <img src="file-icon.png" />This is a file
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I've been searching on google for plugins that I can use for Prototype
>   / Scriptaculous but they seem few and far between and all the ones I
>   have found are geared towards use with PHP.

Based on your question I'm not sure exactly what you need to accomplish.

Prototype & Scriptaculous are add-on libraries for JavaScript, just as jQuery is. They have absolutely **nothing** to do with PHP, Java or any other server-side language because they are part of the client side: JavaScript.

If you're making one to browse files on the *server*, you're simply sending a HTML representations of the file listing to the browser. You would use Prototype to manipulate this HTML.

There are no Javascript-based client-side file browsers, regardless of whether you're using jQuery or Prototype because JavaScript cannot see the local filesystem on the client machine. This was deliberately designed this for security reasons.

Comment: this is what I mean: http://abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/03/jquery-file-tree/ I need something like this but written in Prototype, you don't need to lay it out like I'm a child, maybe I wasn't clear enough, its a file browser to browse server side files, it calls a server-side page and this outputs HTML elements which contain the various files / folders of the system, then the JavaScript manipulates these as needed to display a collabsilbe / expandable file browser. It would be nice if one already has the connectors written for a JSP rather than PHP but I can rewrite for Java if needed

Comment: Here's probably the most complete collection of Prototpye add-ons (http://scripteka.com/) but I doubt you'll find anything similar. You may want to try using no-conflict mode and just doing it in jQuery anyway. I have successfully used both libraries together and it works well.

Comment: thanks, yes I agree I should just do it in Jquery but unfortunately its not my decision to make, I may end up having to just write custom code to do this